# Format of predictions is invalid in R with ROCR package

Tags: r, maxent

I use ROCR package in R.
But I got the error "prediction(predictions, label) : 
  Format of predictions is invalid."

Please tell me the solution.

here is code:

```
install.packages("ROCR", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("vcd",  dependencies=TRUE)
library(ROCR)
library(vcd)
library(boot)

setwd("/Users/Documents/R")

presence <- read.csv("sampleAverages.csv")
background <- read.csv("amplePredictions.csv")
pp <- presence$Logistic.prediction                # get the column of predictions
testpp <- pp[presence$Test.or.train=="test"]       # select only test points
trainpp <- pp[presence$Test.or.train=="train"]   # select only train points
bb <- background$logistic

combined <- c(testpp, bb)                                    # combine into a single     vector
label <- c(rep(1,length(testpp)),rep(0,length(bb)))  # labels: 1=present, 0=random
pred <- prediction(combined, label)                    # labeled predictions
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")               # True / false positives, for ROC curve
plot(perf, colorize=TRUE)                                  # Show the ROC curve
performance(pred, "auc")@y.values[[1]]            # Calculate the AUC
```

Comment: This isn't going to run without data.

Comment: Where is the error?  Had to do much without data.  The ROCR vignette has good step by step examples [here](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/ROCR.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you have wrong class of data. Try modifying the predicted data to just one column like this combined[,2] or label[,2]

Answer (score 0):

check the class of the two objects (label and combined) you notice they are not the same. you can then subset the one with a different dimension with ***dimRid <-  combined[,1]***